# Azure queue triggered function written in visual studio not listening queue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

Azure function created from visual studio is not listening the queue but when I create azure function from portal It listens the queue.

Following are the steps which I did while creating function in visual studio 2017

- I implemented azure queue and passing json string to that queue from
  my .net core application.

  I am able to see entry in queue whenever my .net core code exectued.

  For this created queue, I wrote the azure function in visual
  studio(Queue triggered function).

  I put the connectionstring & queue name while adding the azure
  function.I used entity framework here to do some database
  operation(this is entity framework hence I used 1.0 trigger version
  while creating queue function.I choosed entity framework
  intentionally as I want to do some spatial operations here,Ef core
  just have partial support for this).

  After this,I deploy my visual studio code to Azure app using existing
  publish profile.

Now this created function is not listening to my azure queue.As I am new to azure, there might be chance I am doing some silly mistake here.Any help or suggestion is much appericiated.

1)Crerating function from Portal works fine.

Edit: Added code image 
[Azure function image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUFke.png)

Comment: Is there any error you can see? or do you set the .json file "copy to output directory" to "copy if newer"?

Comment: @IvanYang No error

Comment: For testing purpose, can you please just create a very simple queue trigger azure function, the publish to azure to see if it works? And if it does not work either, please show me the code.

Comment: @IvanYang Yeah I will add..and let you know on this

Comment: @IvanYang Can you please check it now

Comment: checking now, and let you know if any issue.

Comment: some questions: 1.are you creating the azure function from visual studio via azure function template? 2.can you show me the host.json file.  a screenshot is ok(please remember hide your storage credentials).

Comment: I create a v1 function, and it works. you can follow my answer below, and let me if you still have more issues.

Comment: from my experience, v1 has given us so much headaches, and after upgrading to v2 almost all headaches disappeared

Comment: @DnyaneshwarShivbhakta, any update on this issue?

Comment: @IvanYang Its working.Thanks Ivan

Comment: @DnyaneshwarShivbhakta , can you please help mark it as answer? if you don't know how to mark, please follow this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a v1 azure function, code like below(please use **AzureWebJobsStorage** for connection):

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

in local.settings.json(**replace with your own storage connection string**):

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;xxxx",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;xxx"
    }
}
```

and for the **local.settings.json** and **host.json**, right click -> select properties -> then change "copy to output directory" to "copy if newer":

[image]

[image]